# Checking equality for boxed value types of different types when boxed type is unknown

Tags: c#, equality, value-type, boxing

I am comparing an int to a boxed numeric type which is unknown at runtime.  This code does successful value comparisons on unboxed values of different types with the same value:

```
short UnboxedShort = short.MaxValue;
object BoxedShort = short.MaxValue; //this boxed type is unknown at runtime
int UnboxedInt = short.MaxValue;

Console.WriteLine(UnboxedInt == UnboxedShort); //returns true
Console.WriteLine(UnboxedInt.Equals(UnboxedShort)); //returns true
```

This code does not compile because I am using the equality operator on a value type and object:

```
Console.WriteLine(UnboxedInt == BoxedShort); //doesn't compile
```

So, if I do this, it seems like it would work since I am invoking the underlying `.Equals()` method:

```
Console.WriteLine(UnboxedInt.Equals(BoxedShort)); //returns false
```

It returns false.  At first, it appears that it's doing a reference check since the short is boxed within an object.  However, when I compare the unboxed short to the boxed short, it returns `true`:

```
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(BoxedShort, UnboxedShort)); //returns true
```

The only way I can get the comparison to work if the type is unknown is to use `Convert.ChangeType()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(UnboxedInt == (int)Convert.ChangeType(BoxedShort, typeof(int))); //returns true
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(UnboxedInt, Convert.ChangeType(BoxedShort, typeof(int)))); //returns true
```

This isn't the preferred method, though, because `Convert.ChangeType()` is slow based on tests I've run in the past.  Since I will be doing this comparison within iterations, I'd like to avoid `Convert.ChangeType()`.

So what, exactly, is going on in the framework where a boxed short and unboxed short are equal, a boxed short and unboxed int are not equal, but an unboxed short and unboxed int are equal?

**Update**

IvanStoev recommended in comments that I try `Convert.ToInt32()`.  While 3.47x slower than if I unboxed if the type were known (`(int)(short)BoxedShort`) which is obviously not an option, it's still 4.17x faster than `Convert.ChangeType()`.

```
Explicit unbox (175.8 ms)
Convert.ToInt32 (611.6 ms)
Convert.ChangeType (2555 ms)

At 50,000,000 iterations, Convert.ToInt32 is...
   435.80 ms (347.90%) slower than Explicit unbox
    Lose 1 second over 114,731,528 iterations
  1943.40 ms (417.76%) faster than Convert.ChangeType
    Gain 1 second over 25,728,105 iterations
```

I'll wait for a bit to see if any other answers roll in.

Comment: Why not `UnboxedInt == Convert.ToInt32(...`. It should be fast, basically delegating to `IConvertible.ToInt32`

Comment: @IvanStoev Ah, it didn't even occur to me.  Let me test the performance of that real quick.

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated my answer.  You should consider adding your comment as an answer and I'll mark it if no one comes up with a more efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Everything has a logical explanation.

First, when comparing "inboxed" (i.e. typed) value to "unboxed" value of a different type, the compiler takes into account the `implicit` conversions defined and eventually widens one of the values and then uses the respective `==` operator.

When you have a boxed value and using the `Equals` method, the situation is different because `Equals` implementations normally check only for the same type and do not performance. Here is the implementation for the `Int32` taken from the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,13ad4f778352f7c4):

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    if (!(obj is Int32)) {
        return false;
    }
    return m_value == ((Int32)obj).m_value;
}
```

Other implementations are similar. I guess now you see why boxed `int` is not equal to boxed `short` with the same value and vice versa.

Since there is no easy way to unboxing the value w/o knowing the type, you should really use a conversion. All the primitive types implement `IConvertible` which allows converting the boxed value to a desired type (when possible).

However, instead of `Convert.ChangeType` yous should really use [Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys(v=vs.110).aspx) like this

```
bool test = UnboxedInt == Convert.ToInt32(BoxedShort);
```

The reason why this is faster is because `Convert.ChangeType` first need to use type checks and actually call one of the concrete `ToXXX`methods. Second, since the return type of `Convert.ChangeType` is `object`, the value is boxed. And finally you need to unbox it back to `int` (now knowing it will succeed). In other words, additional checks, branches, box and unbox compared to the direct `ToXXX` method call which basically calls `IConvertible.ToXXX` implementation.